# how to moment().fromNow() in angular-moment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

How can I do this moment().fromNow() in angular-moment?

```
<div class="date pull-right"> {{ a.Alert.date }}...</div>
```

How can I apply fromNow() to my variable "a.Alert.date"?

In momentjs I can do this:

```
moment().fromNow()
"a few seconds ago"
moment('2016-12-11').fromNow()
"23 days ago"
```

https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: You haven't shown enough here to reproduce your issue.  What does "this is not working mean"? Where is that code written in your app?

Comment: what do you want to do? format a date? have you looked at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`am-time-ago`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#am-time-ago-directive) directive.

Here a working example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = {
    Alert: {
      date: new Date()
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <span am-time-ago="a.Alert.date"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same thing as you did in Pure JS by simply set `a.Alert.date` as moment Date and call `fromNow` in the view

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, moment) {
  $scope.a = {
    Alert: {
      date: moment()
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="date pull-right"> {{ a.Alert.date.fromNow() }}...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would be reevaluated on every $digest